# Loading many-to-one class - Hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate, proxy, loading

I would like to load a `House` object from database like this:

```
House temp = DataBaseConnector.getInstance().findHouseByID(id);
System.out.println(temp.getType().getName());
```

but anytime I try to access `getType()` field I get error:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy
>   - no Session  at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:165)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:286)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:185)
>     at mapping.Type_$$_jvstd13_0.getName(Type_$$_jvstd13_0.java)
>     ..

`findHouseById` function looks like this:

```
public static House findHouseByID(Integer id) {
    Session session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
    House e = (House) session.load(House.class, id);
    session.close();
    return e;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

As the exception says, you have no (hibernate) session at the point you are calling `temp.getType()` because you closed the session after loading your object within the method `findHouseByID`.

Here some information about object states:

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html

Due to this fact you will get a `LazyInitializationException` because hibernate tries to access the database to propagate the not initialized field `type` on the detached object.

Either you change the fetch strategy of field `type` to `EAGER` so no database access is needed at this point, take a look here:

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/FetchType.html

Or you have to increase the scope of your session (call `getType` before your session is closed).

Comment: I've tried to add EAGER fetch like this: @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
 @JoinColumn(name="type_id")
 public Type getType() {
  return type;
 } But it didnt work.

Comment: Could you please post your related model classes?

Comment: Btw, is it possible that you mixed up property / field access? Did you ever try to annotate the field instead of the getter? http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-entity